# Is it possible to pass variable arguments to the include tag in Mako?

Tags: include, arguments, mako, function

I have a mako template A that includes mako template B more than once. Mako template B expects certain arguments and I need to set them to different values on include.

In A.mak:

```
<%include 
    file="/components/B.mak" 
    args="lItems=some_variable, foo='bar'"
    />

<%include 
    file="/components/B.mak" 
    args="lItems=some_other_variable, foo='moooo'"
    />
```

In B.mak:

```
<%page args="lItems, foo"/>
%for dItem in lItems:
    etc
```

Is this sort of thing even possible? I know it will work if I set lItems to 'some_value' and 'some_other_value' (ie: strings coded directly into A.mak) but I want to render A.mak with `some_variable = [some,craze,list]` and `some_other_variable = [some,other,craze,list]`.

The code above gives me the error:

```
File ".../mako/runtime.py", line 202, in __str__
    raise NameError("Undefined")
NameError: Undefined
```

I also tried doing the includes like so:

```
 <%include 
    file="/components/B.mak" 
    args="lItems=${some_other_variable}, foo='moooo'"
    />
```

but that's a syntax error...

I tried it using a def also:

```
${the_B_def(foo='bar',lItems=some_variable)}
```

and got `NameError: Undefined`.

So my question is: How can I pass variables to templates 'within' a template?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You were almost there:

In A.mak:

```
<%include 
    file="/components/B.mak" 
    args="lItems=some_other_variable, foo='moooo'"
    />
```

In B.mak:

```
<%page args="lItems, foo"/>
%for dItem in lItems:
    ${foo}
%endfor
```

Comment: Docs have an example: http://docs.makotemplates.org/en/latest/syntax.html#include